# How to merge multiple ProxyPass directives in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I need to keep ProxyPass configurations in separate files due to deployment system we use in following form:

File 1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location /qa1/>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8800/qa1/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8800/qa1/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /qa1/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

File 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Location /qa2/>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8801/qa2/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8801/qa2/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /qa2/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but Apache complains that:
[warn] *default* VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence

Any idea if/how it possible to have Apache merge the both configurations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Include`.

File 1: `qa1.conf`

```
<Location /qa1/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8800/qa1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8800/qa1/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /qa1/
</Location>
```

File 2: `qa2.conf`

```
<Location /qa2/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8801/qa2/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8801/qa2/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /qa2/
</Location>
```

File 3: `vhost.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Include qa1.conf
    Include qa2.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, problem is that it basically still requires me update the vhost.conf, rather then merging them both.

Comment: I don't understand why that's a problem.  You only have to update it once when you make this change.  Any changes to the `<Location>` blocks still happen in the two separate files.

Comment: The problem in the deployment system, which basically oriented to separate config files. Having single file forces me to append manually these Includes.

Comment: Are you talking about adding more files in the future such as `qa3.conf` and `qa4.conf` which would require changing `vhost.conf`?  You can use a wildcard in the `vhost.conf` file like this: `Include qa/*.conf` and put the `qa*.conf` files in the `qa/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

just keep the Location directives separately

file qa1.conf

```
<Location /qa1/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8800/qa1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8800/qa1/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /qa1/
</Location>
```

file qa2.conf

```
<Location /qa2/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8801/qa2/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8801/qa2/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /qa2/
</Location>
```

then

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    include qa1.conf 
    include qa2.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Same here, I would prefer to merge them rather then centrally updating a file.