# proxypass /jenkins to port 8080?

Tags: apache-2.2, port, jenkins, proxypass

Hi I have a VPS running cpanel and it is also running Jenkins on port 8080 I have used proxypass in the Apache config to redirect jenkins.rystuff.net to port 8080 but was wondering if there is a way to redirect rystuff.net/jenkins to port 8080 so that ever way you get to my jenkins page
This is what I have used in my httpd.conf to redirect jenkins.rystuff.net to port 8080

```
<VirtualHost 23.227.161.55:80>
    ServerName jenkins.rystuff.net
    ServerAlias jenkins.rystuff.net
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create another vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 23.227.161.55:80>
    ServerName rystuff.net
    ProxyPass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /jenkins http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

You do not need ServerAlias if its the same as ServerName

Comment: Not working just giving me a 404 errror

Comment: Any relevant logs? You might need to do something similar to this, http://serverfault.com/questions/529128/how-to-merge-multiple-proxypass-directives-in-apache